# How to coding function, which subtracts from the matrix column its average value and divides the column by the standard deviation?

Tags: python

Help the coding function that receives the matrix input and subtracts its average value from the column and divides the column by the standard deviation. + you need to check that there is no division by zero. Circles cannot be used.

I'm coding next:

```
def scale(X):
    res = X - np.mean(X, axis = 0)
    return res / np.std(res, axis = 0)[np.std(res, axis = 0) != 0]
```

But in case the matrix has the same values in one column, an error is generated, for example:

```
np.array([3, 6, 6, 8, 1, 3, 1, 3, 8, 4, 3, 6, 7, 7, 4]).reshape((3, 5))
```

[error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3.5) (4,)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDyH4.png)

Tell us how we can solve this problem using numpy and not using loops.

Comment: What result do you expect when the standard deviation is 0?

Comment: "you need to check that there is no division by zero" Okay, but if you find out that there would be a division by zero, what do you want the code to *do about it*?

Comment: I don't know what to do in this case, because the task does not say. I just missed this value so: np.std(res, axis = 0) != 0
I think we should return the matrix number unchanged, but I don't know how to do it.